# jquery ui sortable IE border issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've found strange IE behavior while sorting table rows. In case of the following css style applied on table element

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

all table cells borders disappear.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hetBV/1/)

I've checked also in Chrome and FF but this issue occur only in IE.

Maybe it is possible to apply additional style on dragged row to show borders in IE?

Comment: Top tip: don't use a draggable control on a table - you will have a nightmare with borders/padding/margin etc. You can get around these problems by using `div` elements arranged into a table style.